# Angular.js ng-show just doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with Angular's `ng-show` and I was looking for the answer everywhere and nothing seems to be working. I need form to be showing when button is clicked but it doesn't. Button is calling function that has `console.log` in it and it works but show is not changing its state, here's code:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <form ng-show="show">
     <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Name" required>
   </form>
   <a href="#"class="button large" ng-click="showAddForm()">Show Me!</a>
</div>
```

In app.js:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.showAddForm = function(){
        console.log("click click");
        $scope.show = true;
    }; 
}]);
```

Comment: Have you included angularjs.css file in your project? The element should have `ng-hide` class when it suppose to be hidden

Comment: Can you also try `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` (that would validate Alon's comment)

Comment: I haven't heard about "angularjs.css" file. there's `ng-hide` but after adding `ng-show` whole thing dissappeared so i guess i need to show it first.

Comment: Probably what has happened is that your `$scope.show` is undefined at first. It only becomes `true` when you click.  So you were basically doing `ng-hide="undefined"` which evaluates to `false`.  So it wasn't hiding.  Using `ng-show` does the opposite ... or setting `$scope.show = false` outside of the function would make the hide version work.

Comment: i've linked angular-csp.css and it doesn't help

Comment: @SunilD. still without any effect

Comment: this code works as written, but is using a primitive value type for `show` rather than an object.  without seeing your *entire* project, one might make a *guess* that this isn't working due to scope inheritance issues with primitives. for instance, this code would not function as expected if placed inside an `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the form to be hidden at the beginning and when you click the 'Show Me' button to appear.

If this is the case, your code was 99% there. All you need to do is to initialize `$scope.show` to `false` at the start of the controller code.

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {

    $scope.show = false;

    $scope.showAddForm = function(){
        console.log("click click");
        $scope.show = true;
    }; 
}]);
```

Refer plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/fwVEkEQzztKgOYkLUOsK?p=preview for a full working version.

**Edit : While I was answering your question @Sunil D has already answered with a very good explanation of why its behaving the way its behaving**

Hope this helps

Comment: unfortunately this didn't help i need to do it old fashioned way by removing ng-hide class

Answer (score 0):

Remember you can use a Stackoverflow code snippet in your questions & answers. Your code works if you add the "app" part in html & js:

```js
angular
.module("app",[])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.showAddForm = function(){
        console.log("click click");
        $scope.show = !$scope.show;
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div  ng-app="app" class="row" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <form ng-show="show">
     <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Name" required>
   </form>
   <a href="#"class="button large" ng-click="showAddForm()">Show/Hide</a>
</div>
```